# Allure Jenkins Plugin generating invalid links in html report

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

I am using Allure [jenkins-plugins](/questions/tagged/jenkins-plugins) for report generation and everything is fine except one thing - all links inside allure html report is broken: e.g. expected link to build in 'executors' section should look like:

```
http ://localhost:8080/job/MyJob/1
```

but I'm getting:

```
http ://localhost:8080/job/MyJob/allure/nulljob/MyJob/1
```

and

> Not Found

error on click as per below screenshot:

[image]

Please, help me figure out what reason might stand behind this?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 2.60.2. Tried to disable CSP by running Jenkins war with empty hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP command line argument: "java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar jenkins.war", but that didn't work.

Comment: Also, when I'm clicking on MyJob link, I'm ending up on:
`http: //localhost:8080/index.html`
not 
`http ://localhost:8080/job/MyJob/allure/nulljob/MyJob/1`
That's the browser console output:
`GET http: //localhost:8080/index.html 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved after setting 'Jenkins URL' as suggested in subsequent answer:

[Cannot compute absolute URL when generating Allure report with plugin in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387163/cannot-compute-absolute-url-when-generating-allure-report-with-plugin-in-jenkins#answer-42565409)

Answer (score 0):

What is your Jenkins version ?

Did you make sure your security settings are OK ? 
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/issues/715#issuecomment-180474020

Mor

Comment: Tried running Jenkins with disabled CSP and setting subsequent properties in script console: `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")`

`System.setProperty("jenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")`
But that didn't help.

Comment: 2 Q's : what is your Jenkins version ? Can you see the report without Jenkins ( archive the report and download it .) ?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 2.60.2. And I can see report without Jenkins.